# Oracle Query to fetch data based on only time condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch the data for last six month based on when modified date but the records I need are having time greater than 1500H. Please assist.
I have tried below condition in my script but it's not working:

```
AND WHENMODIFIEDDATE >= to_date('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND WHENMODIFIEDDATE <= to_date('2021-06-01 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND WHENMODIFIEDDATE >= to_date('15:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') ;
```

Data Type for column WHENMODIFIEDDATE: DATE

Sample Data:

```
AUDITORKEY  AUDITORID   AUDITORNAME STATUS  WHENMODIFIEDDATE
9266165     xyz         xyz         A       2020-10-21 08:13:43.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM WHENMODIFIEDDATE) BETWEEN 15 AND 24`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - between 15 and 23 would suffice. :-)

Comment: @mathguy or even `AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM WHENMODIFIEDDATE) >= 15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

AND WHENMODIFIEDDATE >= to_date('15:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')

does not look at hours. If you use the TO_DATE command on just a time component, we will automatically construct a FULL date, eg

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('15:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_DATE('15:00:00',
-------------------
01/08/2021 15:00:00
```

This is why your third predicate is having no effect (or could easily have the wrong effect depending on your date criteria).

As others mentioned in the comments, if you want to get just the HOUR from a date, you can use options such as EXTRACT or TO_CHAR depending on the data type of the source column

```
SQL> create table t ( x timestamp , y date) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (localtimestamp, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select extract(HOUR from x) from t;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMX)
------------------
                11

SQL> select extract(HOUR from y) from t;
select extract(HOUR from y) from t
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source


SQL> select to_number(to_char(y,'HH24')) from t;

TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(Y,'HH24'))
----------------------------
                          11
```